# Querying a parse table and eagerly fetching Relations for matching

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Currently, I have a table named Appointments- on appointments, I have a Relation of Clients.

In searching the parse documentation, I haven't found a ton of help on how to eagerly fetch all of the child collection of Clients when retrieving the Appointments. I have attempted a standard query, which looked like this:

```
 var Appointment = Parse.Object.extend("Appointment");
 var query = new Parse.Query(Appointment);
 query.equalTo("User",Parse.User.current());
 query.include('Rate'); // a pointer object
 query.find().then(function(appointments){
 let appointmentItems =[];
 for(var i=0; i < appointments.length;i++){
      var appt = appointments[i];
      var clientRelation = appt.relation('Client');
      clientRelation.query().find().then(function(clients){
      appointmentItems.push(
            {
                 objectId: appt.id,
                 startDate : appt.get("Start"),
                 endDate: appt.get("End"),
                 clients: clients,  //should be a Parse object collection 
                 rate : appt.get("Rate"),
                 type: appt.get("Type"),
                 notes : appt.get("Notes"),
                 scheduledDate: appt.get("ScheduledDate"),
                 confirmed:appt.get("Confirmed"),
                 parseAppointment:appt
            }
         );//add to appointmentitems
      }); //query.find
    }
 });
```

This does not return a correct Clients collection- 
I then switched over to attempt to do this in cloud code- as I was assuming the issue was on my side for whatever reason, I thought I'd create a function that did the same thing, only on their server to reduce the amount of network calls. 
Here is what that function was defined as:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("GetAllAppointmentsWithClients",function(request,response){
var Appointment = Parse.Object.extend("Appointment");
var query = new Parse.Query(Appointment);
query.equalTo("User", request.user);
query.include('Rate');
query.find().then(function(appointments){
    //for each appointment, get all client items 
   var apptItems =  appointments.map(function(appointment){
           var ClientRelation = appointment.get("Clients");
           console.log(ClientRelation);
           return {
                objectId: appointment.id,
                startDate : appointment.get("Start"),
                endDate: appointment.get("End"),
                clients: ClientRelation.query().find(),
                rate : appointment.get("Rate"),
                type: appointment.get("Type"),
                notes : appointment.get("Notes"),
                scheduledDate: appointment.get("ScheduledDate"),
                confirmed:appointment.get("Confirmed"),
                parseAppointment:appointment
            };
    });
    console.log('apptItems Count is ' + apptItems.length);
    response.success(apptItems);
})
```

});

and the resulting "Clients" returned look nothing like the actual object class:

```
clients: {_rejected: false, _rejectedCallbacks: [], _resolved: false, _resolvedCallbacks: []}
```

When I browse the data, I see the related objects just fine. The fact that Parse cannot eagerly fetch relational queries within the same call seems a bit odd coming from other data providers, but at this point I'd take the overhead of additional calls if the data was retrieved properly.

Any help would be beneficial, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using "[Promises in Series](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-promises-in-series)"

the final code looked something like this:

```
 var Appointment = Parse.Object.extend("Appointment");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Appointment);
    query.equalTo("User",Parse.User.current());
    query.include('Rate');
    var appointmentItems = [];
    query.find().then(function(appointments){

      var promise = Parse.Promise.as(); 
      _.each(appointments,function(appointment){

          promise = promise.then(function(){
            var clientRelation = appointment.relation('Clients');
            return clientRelation.query().find().then(function(clients){
                appointmentItems.push(
                     {
                            //...object details
                     }
                );
            })  
          });
      });
        return promise;
    }).then(function(result){
        // return/use appointmentItems with the sub-collection of clients that were fetched within the subquery. 
    });
```

You can apparently do this in parallel, but that was really not needed for me, as the query I'm using seems to return instantaniously. I got rid of the cloud code- as it didnt seem to provide any performance boost. I will say, the fact that you cannot debug cloud code seems truly limiting and I wasted a bit of time waiting for console.log statements to show themselves on the log of the cloud code panel- overall the Parse.Promise object was the key to getting this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your Cloud code example - `ClientRelation.query().find()` will return a Parse.Promise. So the output `clients: {_rejected: false, _rejectedCallbacks: [], _resolved: false, _resolvedCallbacks: []}` makes sense - that's what a promise looks like in console. The `ClientRelation.query().find()` will be an async call so your `response.success(apptItems)` is going to be happen before you're done anyway.

Your first example as far as I can see looks good though. What do you see as your `clients` response if you just output it like the following? Are you sure you're getting an array of Parse.Objects? Are you getting an empty `[]`? (Meaning, do the objects with `client` relations you're querying actually have clients added?)

```
clientRelation.query().find().then(function(clients){
  console.log(clients);  // Check what you're actually getting here.
});
```

Also, one more helpful thing. Are you going to have more than 100 clients in any given appointment object? Parse.Relation is really meant for very large related collection of other objects. If you know that your appointments aren't going to have more than 100 (rule of thumb) related objects - a much easier way of doing this is to store your client objects in an `Array` within your `Appointment` objects.

With a Parse.Relation, you can't get around having to make that second query to get that related collection (client or cloud). But with a datatype `Array` you could do the following.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Appointment);
    query.equalTo("User", request.user);
    query.include('Rate');
    query.include('Clients'); // Assumes Client column is now an Array of Client Parse.Objects
    query.find().then(function(appointments){
        // You'll find Client Parse.Objects already nested and provided for you in the appointments.
        console.log(appointments[0].get('Clients'));
    });
```

Comment: Wont using an array of parse objects fail if the object is updated, but the array isnt updated to match the new object field?

Im thinking of searching for Appointments for a given client, if the client record is modified then I couldn't do a contains because the objects within the array will be representative a prior version of the client, wont they?

Also, I attempted having a .then() with the logic within the then function to apply the new Appointment record to the array, but the "then" function never fired. I also attempted using the success function on the query but it never fired either-

Comment: Mm, I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying in the first question. But what I meant is to basically redo that column and set the datatype to Array instead of Relation. IF that is an option it is something to consider - if you want that nested data in a single call. Would need to do some Cloud.Job for the transition if you already have data though, might not be worth it as it seems you got what you needed to do anyway.